# FindResource Api gives error 1813 for Text file in a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I have develop a dynamic library, in dll I have added a resource text file and other codes for other purpose, then through a executable I am dynamically loading the dll, when the call goes to FindResource API it always returns NULL. while executable is in separate folder, dynamic library folder is separate one. I can't get why it's not working.
code:
>
 HRSRC hRes = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_XYZ_ABC1), "XYZ_ABC");
<

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: error code is 1813, means resource type not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of FindResource is the handle to load from. So it could be your dynamic dll handle.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 1813 translates to

> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

Passing a `NULL` as the first argument to [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx) is documented to mean:

> If this parameter is NULL, the function searches the module used to create the current process.

If you want to load a resource from an image you load dynamically into a process you have to pass the module's handle to `FindResource`:

```
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("MyResources.dll");
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_XYZ_ABC1), "XYZ_ABC");
// ...
```

If your .dll contains resources only you may want to use [`LoadLibraryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179.aspx) instead. It lets you specify additional load options, allowing you to load a library that consists of resources only, without an entry point.